# java jersey 2.27 trouble in running hello world code

Tags: java, rest, web-services, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Where is the problem ?

I am using Apache tomcat 8.5
I followed this tutorial for [Basic Rest Api example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm)
I followed it step by step, but instead of using **jax-ri 2.17** as they used in the tutorial  i am using **jax-ri 2.27** but resulting in below error:
[image]

If i remove \jaxrs-ri-2.27\jaxrs-ri\ext from lib folder in eclipse i get below Error

[image]

Comment: What jars did you added to lib folder?

Comment: Added all the jars from api,  libs, and ext folder under jaxrs-ri folder

Comment: jersey-server,jersey-media-sse,jersey-media-json-binding,jersey-media-jaxbjersey-hk2,jersey-container-servlet-core,jersey-container-servlet,jersey-common, jersey-client     from lib folder................javax.ws.rs-api-2.1 from api folder and all other 22 from ext folder

Comment: Did you added all to WEB-INF/lib directory ? can you show the folders' content?

Comment: Thanks @user7294900.....I checked in my web.xml file I did not changed the package name  from com.tutorialspoint to com.swapnil.......Now its working....Thanks ......can u suggest me any book or source to properly learning REST API java

Comment: @Swapnil here is a good resource to learn jaxrs: https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-en/content/en/index.html